# perl not executing in cron

Tags: linux, perl, cron

Ok I'm about to pull my hair out. I have a perl script that just will not run in the crontab however I have a previously written perl script that runs just fine every day on the same box. I have checked all of the given solutions on this site and others around the web and nothing seems to make a difference. Here is my cron and the first part of my script

```
55 13 * * * su oracle; cd /u02/oraclebackup;./move_em_bkup.pl >> /u02/oraclebackup/move_em_backup.log > move_em_bkup.dbg 2>$1
```

It touches the .dbg file but does not put anything in there. There are no errors or anything that I can use to go by.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Strict;
use Archive::Tar;
use Net::SCP qw/ scp /;
use Net::SCP::Expect;
use DateTime;
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: I have tried specifying perl path in the cron job and that makes no difference.

Comment: You are redirecting standard output to two different places. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Did you mean `2>&1` instead of `2>$1`?

Comment: try calling perl directly: `perl -c move_em_bkup.pl >>/tmp/plcall.dbg`. this will try to compile your script and print any error messages to the given output file. if the result is something like `Syntax OK`, you may try to actually execute your script in the same way (drop the `-c` option).

Comment: @mob the extra ouput was put in by a coworker and I'm not sure why he did that but yes I meant & instead of $

Comment: @collapsar I have tried calling perl directly I even used the complete path to the perl executable but it did nothing for me but I will try with the -c option and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: output of perl -c option was ./move_em_bkup.pl syntax OK @collapsar

Comment: Cron jobs run with a restricted set of environment variables. It's likely your Perl script depends on some environment variables that you have in your interactive shell.

Comment: @KeithThompson if you notice we su to the user and force it to use the profile so all the environment variables should be available.

Comment: Perhaps you need `su - oracle` rather than `su oracle` (`man su` for details).  But why not put this in the `oracle` account's crontab?

Comment: @KeithThompson Tried that too but thanks. That is why we are so frustrated because it makes no sense.

Comment: Given the syntax you've specified, you are not switching to the `oracle` user to run the later stuff. `su oracle` may work without a password, but the rest of the stuff after the first `;` doesn't run until after `su` has exited and you are back to running as whoever is the owner of the `crontab`. You want to `su oracle -c 'other stuff'` to actually run the other stuff as `oracle`.

Comment: @mob I think fixing that error you caught fixed my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The command you're running is:

```
su oracle; cd /u02/oraclebackup; ...
```

`su oracle` normally launches an interactive shell under the `oracle` account (assuming you have permission to do so). I'm not sure what that would do in a non-interactive `cron` environment, but even assuming it works, the `cd /u02/oraclebackup` and following sub-commands will be executed *after* that shell terminates, i.e., under the account that owns the crontab. The `su oracle` will either block the rest of the command or do nothing.

You can use `su -c command` to run a command as a specified user. In you case, you'd want something like:

```
su -c oracle sh -c 'cd /u02/oraclebackup; ...'
```

Or change `su` to `su -` if you need the `oracle` account's login environment.

Better yet, drop the `su` and put the whole thing in the `oracle` account's crontab. You might still need to play some more tricks to get the environment right; cron jobs run with a limited set of environment variables by default.

Comment: It seems to be working now but I'm not sure why. We are using the oracle crontab but I had the su oracle because that is how the other jobs were created before I started working here.

Comment: Isn't it usually `su oracle -c '...'`?  The synopsis on Mac OS X is ` su [-] [-flm] [login [args]]`, where `oracle` is the login and `-c '...'` are the arguments to the shell.  The basic analysis of the problem is correct — but I don't think the suggested `su -c oracle -c '...'` remedy is correct (it should not use the first `-c`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The man page on Linux says it's `su -c command username`; the synopsis is `su [options] [username]` and `-c COMMAND` is one of the options. But `su username -c command` also works for me.

Comment: @klynch: If you had the command in the root crontab, it may have worked as root. You never said whether that was root's crontab or not. (If `su` is invoked by a non-root user, I'd expect it to prompt for a password.)

Comment: @KeithThompson My mistake. I will try to be more clear next time. I don't have a lot of experience with using cron. I think the issue was a that I screwed up the crontab line. I just wish it would have thrown an error instead just not doing anything.